# GraalVM on Debian armhf

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, armv7, armhf

Is GraalVM currently supported on Debian for armhf architectures? I need a GraalVM that supports Java 17.

I would like to continue using Spring Boot, but the startup time (> 30 seconds for even a minimal application) on the ARM (architecture: armhf) SOM I am using is simply not acceptable. I have heard that using native images with Spring Boot 3 and GraalVM provides a significant improvement in startup time, so I am looking to try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

GraalVM is not provided from debian apt sources but Graal CE(Community Edition) is open source so anyone can compile and use it, [here](https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-dev-builds/releases) are the list coming from original source.

And I ask [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1338979/1150615) long ago and [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417944/1150615), So you can use https://github.com/dongjinleekr/graalvm-ce-deb to build yours and use in **armhf**.

One more solution you can try http://sdkman.io which is very popular in java world for installing any jdk or some more java tools. Here is a complain about [raspbian](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/1148) which is armhf. So it looks like supported. Just for example, "how to install gluon" steps are below

```bash
sdk list java
sdk install java 22.1.0.1.r17-gln
```